# Построить дерево по постфиксной записи

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Не могу разобраться, как правильно описать структуру стек, чтобы в него добавить корень дерева (или как написано в 3-м пункте алгоритма).
Пишу на c++.

Вот отрывок из кода, где описываю структуры.

Структура дерева

```
struct Node
{
    string value;
    Node *left, *right;
};
```

Структура стека

```
struct Temp
{
    char valueA;
    struct valueB;
    Temp *Next;
};
```

Построение из постфиксной записи

Алгоритм Postfix

1. Если не достигнут конец строки ввода, прочитать очередной символ, если этот символ - операнд, то занести его в стек1), иначе (символ - операция):

   ```
   1) создать новый элемент, записать в него эту операцию;
   2) достать из стека два верхних (последних) элемента, присоединить их в качестве левого и правого операндов в новый элемент;
   3) занести полученный "треугольник" в стек.
   ```

По окончании работы этого алгоритма в стеке будет содержаться ровно один элемент - указатель на корень построенного дерева.

Comment: Если это не учебное задание, воспользуйтесь `std::stack`. Если учебное, то толку от того, что мы вам подскажем, не будет, думайте сами.

Comment: @VladD ну тут хоть пробует разобраться, вроде как)

Comment: Мне подсказали, что нужно создать стек, в котором будут хранится ссылки на корни дерева.
Вот мой код:
http://pastebin.com/SHQTUpBR
Но у меня при обходе дерево iTree пустое. :(
1. Помогите пожалуйста, правильно записать тип данных стека
stack <Node> iStackTree;
Мне почему то подозрительно, что тут что то не так, но я не понимаю что не так. 
2. Какая то проблема в функции iStackTree_push() с параметром "function".